# Inserting an image or pdf into a word document in R

Tags: r, for-loop, imagemagick, reporters

Im working with a loop that creates many tables etc. and exports it into word documents with ReporteRs package. So for example I then have a word document with many pages of different graphs, tables and text.

I want to insert an image (or pdf - either is fine) into it through the loop (since the loop produces many different word documents). I have downloaded the ImageMagick and magick packages to work with the images. Now I have my image in R, but I cant figure out how to add it to my document.

I know that ReporteRs has an addImage command that inserts external images (honestly im having trouble figuring that one out to). Is it possible adding internal images/pdf's to a document?

Hope you guys can gives me some tips. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly recommand to migrate your code to `officer` as `ReporteRs` will be removed from CRAN on 2018-07-16. From the code @d125q wrote, this would be transformed as :

```
library(officer)
library(magick)

download.file("https://jeroen.github.io/images/frink.png", "frink.png")
dims1 <- attributes(png::readPNG("frink.png"))$dim/72
sample.image <- image_read("frink.png")
image_write(image_rotate(sample.image, 45), "frink_rotated.png")
dims2 <- attributes(png::readPNG("frink_rotated.png"))$dim/72


sample.doc <- read_docx()
sample.doc <- body_add_img(sample.doc, src = "frink.png", width = dims1[2], height = dims1[1] )
sample.doc <- body_add_img(sample.doc, src = "frink_rotated.png", width = dims2[2], height = dims2[1] )
print(sample.doc, target = "sample.docx")
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! Thats really important information! All of the tables and figures in my code are added to word through ReporteRs. Ill try officer!

Comment: @David Gohel, why does the image need to be rotated?

Answer (score 2):

You can `plot` images from `magick` to add them to a document using `ReporteRs`.  Here's an example:

```
library(ReporteRs)
library(magick)

sample.doc <- docx(title="Sample")

## add original Frink
sample.image <- image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/frink.png")
sample.doc <- addPlot(sample.doc,
                      fun=plot,
                      x=sample.image)

## add rotated Frink
sample.doc <- addPlot(sample.doc,
                      fun=function(x) plot(image_rotate(x, 45)),
                      x=sample.image)


## save the document to disk
writeDoc(sample.doc, "sample.docx")
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering about this with the new officer. I needed to insert a pdf into my document. I converted the pdf to a picture. After migrating to officer, i ended up simply using this code from the officer package:

`img.file <- file.path( R.home("doc201"), "P:/path to my picture", "name.png" )`

`doc201 <- body_add_img(x = doc201, src = "P:/path/name.png", height = 10, width = 6, pos = "after" )`

The other answers worked too, but after i got used to officer this was the most simple way for me. Hope this is of help in the future! :)