# Export images from R to word

Tags: r, officer

I have a code in R with a lot of plots. Copying those plots to a word document manually is too much work, so I am looking for some code that exports those plots directly to a word document. I have tried to use the officer package, but I do not understand it well. I think that with a simple example it will be easier to understand it for me.

For example, suppose I have a code with two easy plots:

```
plot(1,2)
plot(0,0)
```

How can I create a word document in which this two plots appear? Thank you very much!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172522/inserting-an-image-or-pdf-into-a-word-document-in-r

Comment: You can render an RMarkdown document to a Word document, that might be an easy route to go